# Blendswap log in problem (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

Tags: modeling, materials, blend-files, error

I can´t log into Blendswap site. Does anyone have same problem? My browser gives me this error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. I have tried different computers, browsers and internet connections.

Otherwise site works perfectly.

Log in feature has not worked now for two days!

Comment: This is likely a Blendswap site error, and is out of scope for this site, in my opinion. Raise a help issue with the Blendswap site team.

Comment: You are right! Only problem is that there is no way to contact them. They don´t have help-desk emails and contact form needs log in to work. Situation would be different if they would report about this problem on their site. I don´t even know, do they know about this problem...

Comment: i try to login and same error, is a Blendswap site error. and its not related to blender or this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be reported to Blendswap, the problem is not related directly to the use of the Blender software

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Blender

Comment: Sorry about misunderstanding. You can close this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I'm having the same issue as well. At first I checked a website to see if the website was down, but it said it was fine. And honestly, I can see the webpage itself, but as you said whenever I've tried to login it gives me the same error message.

Probably should just try logging in tomorrow morning.

Comment: This is comforting to hear. This really cause problems to my projects. Bad service from Blendswap.